# How can I refer to 'self' in a model definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Please ignore the ruby meaning of 'self' in my question.** I mean it in the standard English way.

I've got a model called subscription and I have added a definition called subscribed.

I want to do something like:

```
  def subscribed
    @subscription = Subscription.where(:thread_id => this.thread_id, :user_id => this.user_id)
  end
```

where `this` refers to the current instance, not some global class.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `self` in the places where you wrote `this` (or just leave it out altogether), it **will** refer to the current instance and not "some global class".

Comment: I think by "current instance" he means "The Subscription object currently being inspected by the `where` method."

Comment: @Chuck: I can't imagine that's what he meant. If he did, `:thread_id => this.thread_id, :user_id => this.user_id` would not make any sense.

Comment: Truthfully, it didn't make a whole lot of sense to me either way. That just seemed to be what he was trying to indicate by saying "Ignore the Ruby meaning of `self`."

Answer (score 2):

Just use field names and it should work

```
def subscribed
  @subscription = Subscription.where(:thread_id => thread_id, :user_id => user_id)
end
```